# My chrome extension is pretty large and event driven. What are some ways I can optimize?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which is quite big. It relies on external frameworks as well as custom code. The extension manipulates the DOM and my fear is that it would really slow chrome down for some users especially if it is loaded on every tab.

Questions

1. Are chrome extensions loaded per tab?
2. Is there an upper or suggested limit to how big your extension should be?

Comment: Code size is irrelevant. Depends when it runs, what it does and how often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions downloaded by the Chrome browser upon install are subsequently run off of the local disk in order to speed up performance. If a new version of the extension is pushed online, it will be automatically downloaded in the background to any users who have the extension installed.

Answer to the second one I don`t think so.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the first question:

chrome extension code might be injected to web page using content script, you need to specify which host you want to inject script to.

So it is not a question of will chrome extension be loaded per tab, you need to specify whether you want your extension to load per tab.

You can request the extension to load only in the web sites that you want it to load.

[see content script here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)